# Woocommerce - Need to Override Message "Invalid downlod link. Go to Shop"

Tags: woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I'm trying to override the message **"Invalid downlod link. Go to Shop"** when a download link expires. This message is contained inside class-wc-download-handler.php

I need a snippet I can drop in functions.php or a way to cleanly override the file. Any help is greatly appreciated.

I tried to override the file using the child template structure: **child theme > Woocommerce > includes > class-wc-download-handler.php** but is not working.

Comment: This is simply not possible: you can't override WooCommerce core files via your theme, you can only override template files.

Comment: I understand. Any other way then to change this message? The situation is I need to change the message to Spanish for a customer of mine including a custom link.

Comment: You can use [gettext filter hook](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A3730754+gettext) or you can also use a plugin like [Loco Translate](https://wordpress.org/plugins/loco-translate/)